# Reorganización dataframe

Tags: r, rstudio

estoy trabajando con dataset de datos longitudinales. Tal y como están se muestra como (con 515 filas, cambiando de sujeto lo que interpreto que es cada 5):

```
id    treatment    month  cholesterol
1     placebo       0         251
1     placebo       6         262
1     placebo       12        239
2     chenodiol
...
```

Lo que querría (y necesito para poder graficar) es transformar mi tabla a algo de la forma:

```
        x1       x2    x3    y1     y2
1       251     262    239    0      6 
2
...
```

etc, donde las filas muestran como primer elemento el id, y los xi hacen referencia todos los valores de colesterol para primer id y yi los meses o month.

Muchas gracias, toda ayuda es bienvenida.
Adjunto el paquete exacto para facilitar su implementación.

```
install.packages("ALA", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")

library(ALA)
names(cholest)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con `dplyr/tidyverse` puedes usar [`pivot_wider()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html) primero necesitarás generar un numerador por fila y por cada grupo de `id`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(id, treatment) %>% 
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = n, 
              values_from = c(month, cholesterol))

# A tibble: 1 x 8
# Groups:   id, treatment [1]
     id treatment month_1 month_2 month_3 cholesterol_1 cholesterol_2 cholesterol_3
  <int> <chr>       <int>   <int>   <int>         <int>         <int>         <int>
1     1 placebo         0       6      12           251           262           239
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!! Esto me ha ayudado mucho, desconocía pivot_wider :)