# Ubicar valores de un mismo grupo en una sola celda concatenados

Tags: r

Salud@s. Tengo un dataframe similar a sp_df, solo que con muchas más especies:

```
 sp <- c(rep("Anisognathus melanogenys",5),rep("Anthocephala berlepschi",3),"Anthocephala floriceps")

hab1 <- c(109,307,1402,1403,105,107,502,510,900) 

sp_df <- data.frame(sp1, hab1)
```

Cada especie puede tener 1 o más códigos asociados y me gustaría que los datos se reorganizaran en un nuevo **dataframe** en el que cada especie aparezca en la primera columna una sola vez, y en la segunda columna aparezcan concatenados sus respectivos códigos. Algo así:

```
Anisognathus melanogenys 109,307,1402,1403,105
Anthocephala berlepschi  107,502,510
Anthocephala floriceps   900
```

Tengo entendido que se puede usar la función *do.call*... pero aún no se como usarla bien :(.
Agradezco mucho cualquier indicación :)

Comment: Hace un rato, respondí esta pregunta que es exactamente lo que estás preguntando:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/460496/reorganizaci%c3%b3n-dataframe/460743?noredirect=1#comment819705_460743 dime si tienes alguna dificultad para adaptarla a tu requerimiento, y eventualmente si te sirvió, para no repetir contenido te sugiero que elimines tu pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Agradezco mucho tu ayuda, no solo en esta pregunta sino en otras varias :). El día de mañana retiraré la pregunta para no repetir contenido. Mil gracias